# Proposal Period Voting style

Tags: governance, voting

In the current Proposal Period, why is the Approval Voting/Upvoting mechanism used as opposed to Preferential Voting/Ranked-Choice voting or just the plain old First-Past-the-Post voting?

Were there any specific design choices considered for this? And also why up to 20 proposals?

Comment: could you please define the other mode of voting you are refering to in your question ? some links and/or short descriptions would help, thanks!

Comment: Ranked Voting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranked_voting ; 
First-past-the-post voting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-past-the-post_voting

Comment: This seems better suited for discussion here: https://forum.tezosagora.org/